# Spaced time mixed partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am trying to reproduce solution of the following differential equation.
[image: Differential equation]

I know its solution is

[image]

I tried the following code.

```
equ = NDSolve[{D[u[\[Tau], r], {\[Tau], 1}] - 
     D[u[\[Tau], r], {r, 2}] - ((1/r)*D[u[\[Tau], r], {r, 1}]) == 0}, 
  Derivative[0, 1][u][\[Tau], 0] == 0, 
  Derivative[0, 1][u][\[Tau], RC] == -h*u, u[0, r1] = u0, 
  u[0, r2] = 0, {0 <= r1 >= R}, {R <= r1 >= RC}, {r, 0, RC}, {\[Tau], 
   0, Infinity}]
```

but ended with the error `"NDSolve::dsvar:$u^{0,1}[\tau,RC]=-hu$ cannot be used as a variable.` I want to solve this equation keeping both **$`h`$** and **$`u`$** as variables and reproduced the given solution. Currently, I am out of idea how to deal with it.

Waiting for some valuable directions and suggestions.

Note: In my code a=R and b=RC.

Answer (score 6):

```
x0 = 10^-10; xN = 2; a = 1; t0 = 1; h = .5; u0 = 1;
eq = D[u[t, x], t] - D[u[t, x], x, x] - D[u[t, x], x]/x == 0;
ic = u[0, x] == Piecewise[{{u0, x < a}}, 0];
bc = {Derivative[0, 1][u][t, x0] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1][u][t, xN] == -h*u[t, xN]};
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, t0}, {x, x0, xN}]; // Quiet
Plot3D[sol[t, x], {t, 0, t0}, {x, x0, xN}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x"}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thanks Alex, How I can solve this differential equation for an Analytical solution like the one I have mentioned using  DSolve or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Your bc's set up nicely, so we can solve this pde as a function of `u[t,r]`.  The problem is the singular term `u'[r]/r` at `r = 0`, but since you have specified that `u'[0] == 0` we have `0/0` at `r = 0` so we can use L'Hospital's rule to get the limit there.  Taking derivatives of the numerator and denominator we see that `u'[r]/r -> u''[r]/1` for `r = 0`.  Define the pde in Piecewise form as:

```
pde = D[u[t, r], {r, 2}] + Piecewise[{{D[u[t, r], {r, 2}], r == 0}, {D[u[t, r], r]/r, r > 0}}] == D[u[t, r], t]
```

Now NDSolve has no problem at `r = 0`.

the bc's are:

```
bc1 = Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0] == 0
bc2 = Derivative[0, 1][u][t, RC] == -h*u[t, RC]
```

the initial condition

```
ic = u[0, r] == Piecewise[{{u0, r < R}}, 0]
```

Plug in some values so NDSolve can actually do something.

```
R = 1;
RC = 3 R;
h = 1;
u0 = 1;

sol = NDSolve[{pde, bc1, bc2, ic}, u[t, r], {t, 0, 10}, {r, 0, RC}];

u[t_, r_] = u[t, r] /. %[[1]];
```

Plot the solution.

```
tb = Table[Plot[Evaluate[u[t, r]], {r, 0, RC}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {t, 0, 5, .1}];

ListAnimate[tb]
```

[image]

I don't know if there is a way that `DSolve` can solve the problem analytically directly, but it should be relatively easy through separation of variables.

Add separation of variables solution.

At first look for separable solutions of the type `u = R[r]*T[t]`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

pde = D[u[r, t], {r, 2}] + (1/r)*D[u[r, t], r] == D[u[r, t], t]

u[r_,t_]=R[r]T[t]

pde = Expand[pde[[1]]/u[r, t] == pde[[2]]/u[r, t]]

R''[r]/R[r]+R''[r]/(r R[r])==T''[t]/T[t]
```

Left side is dependent only or `r` and right side is dependent only on `t`.  So each side must be equal to the same constant.  That constant can be 0, >0, or <0, each case giving a different set of solutions.  In this case a negative constant is the only one we need.

```
$Assumptions= c>0

teq=pde[[2]]==-c^2

DSolve[teq,T[t],t]//Flatten;

T1=(T[t]/.%/.C[1]->1);

req= pde[[1]]==-c^2;

DSolve[req,R[r],r]//Flatten;

R1=(R[r]/.%/.{C[1]->c1,C[2]->c2});
```

The solution then becomes:

```
un[r_,t_]=R1 T1
(*E^(-c^2 t) (c1 BesselJ[0,c r]+c2 BesselY[0,c r])*)
```

Recognizing that we will have an infinite series of un's.
The solution must be finite at origin, so

```
c2=0
```

Apply the boundary condition

```
bc=(D[un[r, t], r] /. r -> b) + h*un[b, t] == 0//Collect[#, {c1, E^(-t c^2)}]&
(*c1 E^(-c^2 t) (h BesselJ[0,b c]-c BesselJ[1,b c])==0*)
```

This equation sets the values of c.  There are an infinite number of them and they are the roots of:

```
ceq=(h BesselJ[0,b c]-c BesselJ[1,b c])==0
```

Solve the above for BesselJ[1,b c] so we can substitute later.

```
csol=Solve[ceq,BesselJ[1,b c]]//Flatten;
```

Use the ic for `u[r,0]` to get `c1`.  We will use the orthogonality of `BesselJ0`.
The ic is easiest( for me) to define in terms of `UnitStep` functions.

```
ic=un[r,0]==u0(UnitStep[r]-UnitStep[r-a])
(*c1 BesselJ[0,c r]==u0 (UnitStep[r]-UnitStep[r-a])*)
```

Multiply both sides of the above by `r BesselJ0[r c]` and Integrate over `r` from `a` to `b`

```
$Assumptions=$Assumptions&&a>0&&b>a

Integrate[ic[[1]]*r*BesselJ[0, c*r], {r, 0, b}] == Integrate[ic[[2]]*r*BesselJ[0, c*r], {r, 0, b}];
```

Apply the condition for c

```
%/.csol//Simplify

Solve[%,c1]//Flatten;

c1=c1/.%
```

We end up with

```
un[r,t]/.c->c[[n]]

(2 a u0 c[[n]] E^(-t c[[n]]^2) BesselJ[1,a c[[n]]] BesselJ[0,r c[[n]]])/(b^2 (c[[n]]^2+h^2) BesselJ[0,b c[[n]]]^2)
```

The actual answer as an infinite sum over the c's.

```
u[r_, t_] := ((2*a*u0)/b^2)*Sum[(c[[n]]*BesselJ[1, a*c[[n]]]*BesselJ[0, r*c[[n]]])/
     (E^(t*c[[n]]^2)*((c[[n]]^2 + h^2)*BesselJ[0, b*c[[n]]]^2)), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

Plug in some numbers so we can plot.

```
a=1;
b=3 a;
h=1;
u0=1;
```

Solve for the c's from

```
F1[c_]=ceq[[1]]
(*BesselJ[0,3 c]-c BesselJ[1,3 c]*)
```

I really tried to use `NSolve` in the following form to solve for the c's, because it has worked before on other problems:

```
c=d/.NSolve[{F1[d],d>=0&&d<=100},d];
```

I got an array of most of the values, but some were missing.  Increasing the `WorkingPrecision` up to 200 added some but still did not get all of them.
So using `FindRoot` manually, first plot the first two values to get a starting point.

```
Clear[c];
Plot[F1[c],{c,0,2}]
```

[image]

Find 200 values

```
n = 200; 
c = Table[0, {i, n}]; 
aa = FindRoot[F1[\[Beta]] == 0, {\[Beta], 0.6}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 15];
c[[1]] = \[Beta] /. aa; 
aa = FindRoot[F1[\[Beta]] == 0, {\[Beta], 1.5}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 15];
c[[2]] = \[Beta] /. aa; 
For[i = 3, i <= n, aa = FindRoot[F1[\[Beta]] == 0, {\[Beta], 2*c[[i - 1]] - c[[i - 2]]}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 15]; 
   c[[i]] = \[Beta] /. aa; i++]
Clear[n]

u[r_, t_, m_] := ((2*a*u0)/b^2)*Sum[(c[[n]]*BesselJ[1, a*c[[n]]]*BesselJ[0, r*c[[n]]])/
     (E^(t*c[[n]]^2)*((c[[n]]^2 + h^2)*BesselJ[0, b*c[[n]]]^2)), {n, 1, m}]
```

We have slow convergence for `u` at `t = 0` since `Exp[-c^2 t]` does not contribute.  Check that we satisfy the initial condition with the 200 terms.

```
Plot[Evaluate[u[r,0,200]],{r,0,b}]
```

[image]

Matches the ic within numerical tolerance.
For `t > 0` the series converges with many fewer terms.

```
tb1=Table[Plot[Evaluate[u[r,t,20]],{r,0,b},PlotRange->{0,1}],{t,0,5,.1}];
ListAnimate[tb1]
```

[image]

It's pretty much the same as the `NDSolve` solution, but the analytical solution was certainly not as quick.

Comment: Thanks Bil Watts, for this nice valuable comment. I am trying to solve this on paper pen if failed then I will rise another question as u suggested.